# Glassfish - 3.1.2 deployment of a EAR package takes very long

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish

We have a ear package with:

3 war packages,
77 ejb packages,
101 jar packages

The deployment of this ear package takes about 30 minutes.
It is too long for developers.
How can we analyse the deployment time on glassfish?

Do I get more information about deploying, when I turn on the log level for some packages in logging.properties?

When I set **javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.level** to FINEST, I see at the start many entries like:

```
*Fein: Adding jar to class path:file:/D:..../.jar*
*Fein: Adding jar to class path:file:/D:..../.jar*
```

than

```
*Fein: FileArchive.getSubArchive for D:...*
```

after that comes only

```
Fein: Skipping D:\Glassfish_3.1.2_Developer\glassfish\domains\ascDomain\autodeploy\bundles because its name is in the list of files to ignore
```

and nothing more for 15-20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You could do some profiling with one of the various programs that do that for java and maybe see what is the slowest part.  Also, go vote for this issue:  http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16560

Comment: Unfortunately, we have found anything with jvisualvm and netbeans profiler. 
The dol.jar from posted bug gives us no performace improvement. Nevertheless thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

fixed using:

http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18875